# XAMPP Symbolic link Access Forbidden

Tags: xampp, symlink

For a xampp server I have created a symbolic link.

Now when running the server I get an error:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

In the project directory I currently only have an `index.html` file containing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I have checked all the permissions on both the project directory and the directory the symbolic link is located in.
These are all set to 777.

What could I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create virtual host in apache configuration.
I would recommend using pure apache without xampp on most unix based systems, but with xampp it's still possible.

Find your apache config directory and head to extra folder, it should be organised with something like:  `\xampp\apache\conf\extra\`

Add listener and virtual host on the bottom of the file like that

```
ServerName localhost
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "diretory/with/index/"
    <Directory "directory/with/all/files">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The main difference between DocumentRoot and Directory is that DocumentRoot must point directly to the place where you index.php is located.
Directory is just poinitng to the all resources places.

For example you can have `stuff/public` folder in which are located all things that user can access, but also you have some frameworks like laravel which is upper in directory and still needs to be maintained by php interpreter, but shouldn't be accessible directly to the end user

Comment: I know that this question is kinda old, but I've faced this issue recently and honestly, without any outer help and some brainstorming I would never resolve this issue, so I hope it would make someone life easier